# Power Bi - Employee Attrition Rate

Tags: analytics, powerbi-desktop

I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets.
The first worksheet is not really usable in PowerBI (I think), but I get a decent overview about the **employee attrition**. (I calculated the changes on the right side)

[image: Worksheet 1]

In the second worksheet I have two columns from which I think I could calculate the **year-to date** and **year-to-year** attrition rate: The **date of hire** and the **date of termination**.
What is weird for me that in the second worksheet I have the same amount of hire date as termination date, which means I can only calculate the attrition rate without having a column with data pointing on those who stayed.

[image: Worksheet 2]

I'm not sure how to proceed with this in PowerBI

To be honest I am not sure how to start without having data about those who stay in the company.
I think what I need is a way to tell, that in a specific time how many of those who were hired are still working there.

I calculated the duration in a different column, showing the number of days of the employment status.